# connect as3 to mysql not work

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I tried to link my actionscript3 application to the database ... Here are my codes.

**MY AS3 CODE:**

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

const SENT_SUCCESS:String = "Successful";
const SENT_FAILED:String  = "Unsuccessful";

var tmr:Timer;

function resetTextFields():void {
    username.text = String("username");
    password.text = String("password");
}

function afterTmrWait(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    tmr.stop();
    tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, afterTmrWait);
}

function submitForm(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var passChecks:Boolean = true;

    if(username.text == String("")) {
        passChecks = false;<br>
    }
    if(password.text == String("")) <br>{<br>
        passChecks = false;
    }

    if(passChecks) {
        var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/login.php");
        var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        urlVars.username = username.text;
        urlVars.password = password.text;

        urlReq.data = urlVars;
        urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, serverFeedback);
        ldr.load(urlReq);
        ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    }
}

function serverFeedback(evt:Event):void {
    var ldr:URLLoader = evt.target as URLLoader;
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(ldr.data);

    if(urlVars.result == SENT_SUCCESS) {
        login_result.gotoAndStop(2);
        resetTextFields();
    } else if(urlVars.result == SENT_FAILED) {
        login_result.gotoAndStop(3);
    }

tmr = new Timer(3000, 1);
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, afterTmrWait);
tmr.start();
}

login_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitForm);
resetTextFields();
```

**MY PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(exist($_POST['username']) && exist($_POST['password'])) {
    $mysql = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password", "database"); 

    $password = md5(stripslashes($mysql->real_escape_string($password)));
    $outcome = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}' LIMIT 1");

    if(!$outcome->null_rows) { 
        echo( "result=Unsuccessful" ); 
    } else {
        echo( "result=Successful" );
    } 
}

?>
```

**AND I GET THIS ERROR IN FLASH:**

```
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

**PLEASE HELP ME, WHAT I DO WRONG?**

Comment: you should tell whats wrong, otherwise no one will help you

Comment: when it starts it goes, but when you press button you get error and I do not know why. it not work, where is mistake? I already tried everything, but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The URLLoader dataFormat by default is text. You need to add

```
ldr.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

so it does throw an error when you try

```
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(ldr.data);
```

Comment: now i have this error:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at app_fla::MainTimeline/submitForm()

Comment: Use the debugger to step through "submitForm". A variable is null or doesn't have the property you think it does. Also, the "<br>" tags are only in your code listed here and not in your runtime code?

Answer (score 0):

set dataFormat before load request..

your code

```
ldr.load(urlReq);
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

try this....

```
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
ldr.load(urlReq);
```